# Parallel.For/Foreach loop take elements outside of a list in synchronized order

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I have a parallel for loop and a list which looks like this:

```
 var itemsList = new List<string> { "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11" };

 Parallel.For(0, 5000, ex=>
 {

 });
```

What I would like to do here:

- Take out elements from itemsList one by one in exact order as they are in the list, regardless of the parallel iteration being called randomly

So basically in first random parallel operation  item under "1" value would be stored in the first variable like following:

```
var itemFromList = itemList.elementAt(0).Take(1);
```

In second iteration of parallel foreach/for loop:

```
var itemFromList = itemList.elementAt(1).Take(1);
```

Once all 11 items from the list have been used.. I'd just like to repeat this process once allover again.

Then again if the last item that was stored into the variable:

```
var itemFromList = itemList.elementAt(10).Take(1); // Last item
```

And then again first item from the list is used again:

```
var itemFromList = itemList.elementAt(0).Take(1);
```

Iteration repeats like this indefinitely.

Can someone help me out with this one ?

Comment: @RufusL I woulndn't want to remove the item from the list at all. They need to be there present in the list at all times :D

Comment: Why not just reference the items by index instead of using `Take` (which returns an `IEnumerable`)

Comment: @RufusL yes but how to do it dynamically... :D ? ElementAt() should receive a dynamic parameter, not a static one like in my case ^^

Comment: _"in exact order"_ is in conflict with `Parallel`. Chose one or the other.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes but I'm not accessing the items from the parallel.for loop , I understand that , I'm not trying to access that list, but the second one which isn't being looped through ? :D

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Why are you using [`Parallel.For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=netframework-4.7.2) if you want to do things in a particular order? From the documentation, *Executes a `for` loop in which iterations may run in parallel*, so by definition you have no control over the order in which things happen. I think you might need to clarify exactly what you're trying to do, possibly with a real-world example?

Comment: @RufusL Yes but I'm not accessing the list within the parallel.foreach loop(the one which is being looped through?)

Comment: @RufusL There is second list if you can see, itemList is not the one being looped through in parallel.foreach

Comment: What is the excepted value of 'itemFromList`? Is it 1,2,..,10,11,1,2,3,...,10,11,1,2... (5000 elements)?

Comment: @SarveshMishra expected values frmo itemFromList can be : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 => value from that list up above that is defined before the parallel foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will execute on all elements the same amount of times.
And as long as you only read from the list it should be thread-safe.

But 'sequential in time' is not compatible with going Parallel.

```
 Parallel.For(0, 5000, ex=>
 {
    int myIndex = ex % itemsList.Count;
    string myItem = itemsList[myIndex];
    // use myItem
 });
```

Comment: Henk thank you ! :D What after the last items is being accessed ? Will it take then again the first item from the list after the last one was used ?

Comment: Yes, that is what the `%` does.

Comment: the output that I get on screen is like: 1 6 11 5 2 7 1 6 :(

Comment: Yes, and it could be different each run. What did you expect?

Comment: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11  ? :D

Comment: Then do not use Parallel. Use a `for(...)`.